# How to load jquery ui autocomplete combobox?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have tried below script to load jQuery UI Autocomplete in theme. But it doesn't load their related scripts. How should I call it to work.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete');
```

I think below scripts are jQuery UI related scripts for autocomplete but it's doesn't load.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the script in the footer section.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#clientAutocomplete").autocomplete({
                        source:'client_autocomplete.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

This worked for me

Comment: I think it isn't WP prefer method but jquery-ui.min.js was loaded. Unfortunately still trouble to use autocomplete combobox feature. Anyway thanks for your help @1991wp

Comment: According to the demo `_create: function() {` didn't work so no more input to work as demo.

Answer (score 0):

As for the stylesheets: WordPress does not register jQuery UI styles by default!

You have to include the theme you want by calling `wp_enqueue_style()`. Since you need the right version, you can call `wp_scripts()` and check for the registered jQuery UI core version.

[See details](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273986/correct-way-to-enqueue-jquery-ui/273996)