# JQuery UI Autocomplete showing as bullets

Tags: php, plugin-development, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The JQuery UI Demo page for autocomplete has a nice looking search box and drop down. When I implement it in my plugin, I end up with a bulleted list. How do I get my drop down of suggestions to look like theirs?As results shown in console but just bullet points here. [image]

Yes,this is my code i applied some css by inspecting classes but the issue not resolved.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // ... Your existing code ...
    console.log('Autocomplete initialized'); 

    // Autocomplete functionality
    $('#search-input').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                url: custom_woocommerce_search_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'custom_woocommerce_auto_suggest',
                    search_query: request.term,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                     response(data);
                     console.log(data);
                         // Clear previous suggestions
   
   
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error:', error);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2, // Minimum characters before triggering autocomplete
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // Handle selection if needed
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a styling issue that might be more appropriate on StackOverflow. On either site you'll want to include your plugin code so folks can help - it wouldn't be possible to troubleshoot without knowing what the markup looks like.

Comment: Yes , i added the code plz check

Comment: Have you enqueued the jQuery UI styles, e.g. the [base theme](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)? Because WordPress does *not* load the styles automatically, only the script. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/273996

Comment: I enqueue these style and scripts for Jquery autocomplete ui. 
 wp_enqueue_style("jquery-ui-styles");
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-autocomplete");

Comment: Either your theme or another plugin could be the culprit. Inspecting the elements to find out which element the bullets are on, and which stylesheet is applying them, should give you enough information to override them. Without access to the codebase anyone else would just be guessing.

Comment: Okay Thank you so much , I try